# Pandas : median of column grouped by other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as such

```
 plan_id route_id   dtn
   801      12289     2629.0
   801      12289     1666.0
   801      12289     7700.0
   801      12289     2216.0
   801      7734      2219.0
   801      7734      853.0
   653      8819      3375.0
   653      8819      2184.0
```

dtn is in seconds. and dtn is the distance to next delivery in the route, i.e., at index 3 that would be the distance between delivery index 3 and delivery index 4.**

I need to find the median distance travelled for each route_id per given plan_id and append it as a column to the existing dataframe matched to the corresponding pid and route_id.

I initially summed the dtn to find the total distance travelled per route(route_id) and plan_id using

```
df=df.groupby(['plan_id','route_id'])['dtn'].sum().reset_index()
```

I then decided to group by once more using plan_id and route_id to get the median using

```
df.groupby(['plan_id','route_id')['dtn'].median()
```

It however returns the same summed data frame back without any changes. It is worth noting that a plain_id can have multiples routes(route_id) and vice versa.

Comment: Can't I get it if I ask for the median first without asking for the sum in the grouping? It may just be my environment, but even if I get the median after finding the total, the total and the median are displayed the same as the total, so the total is not acquired.

Comment: because dtn is originally the distance from point A to point B in a route and a route has many stops. it is not the total distance travelled in a particular route. so if you dont sum it you only get the median distance to the next delivery in a route.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the median of a given plan id and rout_id, why do you use sum?
using the df you presented:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
"plan_id":[801,801,801,801,801,801,653,653],
"route_id": [12289,12289,12289,12289,7734,7734,8819,8819],
"dtn":[2629,1666,7700,2216,2219,853,3375,2184]})
```

I changed the dtn column to small numbers so it is easier to understand the median:

```
df["dtn"]=range(1,9)
df
    plan_id route_id    dtn
  0  801    12289       1
  1  801    12289       2
  2  801    12289       3
  3  801    12289       4
  4  801    7734        5
  5  801    7734        6
  6  653    8819        7
  7  653    8819        8
```

From this example you can see that the median of pid 801 given route_id 12289 is the median of this group of numbers:[1,2,3,4]. meaning  2.5

median of pid 801 and route id 7734 is the median of [5,6], so it's 5.5 and so on..

the result can be obtained with:

```
    grouped=df.groupby(['plan_id','route_id'])['dtn'].median().reset_index()
    grouped
    plan_id route_id    dtn
    0   653 8819        7.5
    1   801 7734        5.5
    2   801 12289       2.5
```

now you can join your df with the grouped one in order to get the median for each pid and route id as a column

```
df.merge(grouped, left_on=['plan_id','route_id'],right_on= 
['plan_id','route_id'],suffixes=("","_median"))
    plan_id route_id    dtn dtn_median
  0  801    12289          1    2.5
  1  801    12289          2    2.5
  2  801    12289          3    2.5
  3  801    12289          4    2.5
  4  801    7734           5    5.5
  5  801    7734           6    5.5
  6  653    8819           7    7.5
  7  653    8819           8    7.5
```

Comment: because dtn is the distance to next delivery, or rather distance between observation i and observation i +1. my question to find the median of the distance travelled. if I do what you mentioned, i will get the median distance between i and i+1 observation grouped by plan and route id.